# How to put a file input anywhere in the DOM with p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using `createFileInput()` from the P5.js library. *More info on that [here](https://github.com/shiffman/A2Z-F16/blob/gh-pages/week1-strings/03_loadFile_Menu/sketch.js).*

```
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  var fileInput = createFileInput(addedFile);
}
```

When I use this in my `setup` function it simply adds the element to the end of the HTML page. I cannot figure out how to place the input anywhere within my page, like between some `span` tags.

I've tried `.html()`, `.value()` and even tried placing it directly inline in the HTML file but I cannot get it to appear where I want it. Usually it just disappears or I get an error.

I've tried using [this tutorial](http://shiffman.net/a2z/intro/) and looking at the js to figure out how he placed it in the middle of the page but I can't even find that!

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first stop should be [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.dom).

Specifically, it looks like the [`parent()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent) function does what you want: it takes an element you created in your P5.js code (in your case, your `fileInput` variable) and moves it into a parent element in the HTML webpage.

So your first step would be to create an html webpage that contains an element (probably a `<div>`) in the middle of the page. Then you'd write P5.js code that calls the `parent()` function and passes in the id of that `<div>` element.